# writing a date to oracle table using mvc

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I am using mvc and I want to insert a date to an oracle database. I stored the value
in an object then add it to a collection (processed_date). I then used the insert statement
to write to the database.

All I get it invalid date format. Do you have any idea how I can fix this? I need to write the exact date "31/12/2099" to the Oracle database.

```
            object col14Value = "31/12/2099";

            processed_date = (col14Value).ToString()

            string sqlIns = "insert into price_line (processed_date) values (to_date(:processed_date, mm/dd/yyyy)
```

The property of the processed_date looks like this

```
 public string processed_date { get; set; }
```

Now I am begining to the the error below

[Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException] = {"ORA-01843: not a valid month"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mm/dd/yyyy should be encased in quotes - 'mm/dd/yyyy'. It is an Oracle string. Also if your date is 31/12/2099 then your format string should be 'dd/mm/yyyy'